# Use advanced filter for a series of similar 'search and replace' filters

Tags: regex, google-analytics, filtering

I have multiple `Search and Replace` filters that remove a sequence of numbers from the page path.

For example `Search String`

```
/abc/.*[0-9]/
/def/.*[0-9]/
/ghi/.*[0-9]/
/jkl/.*[0-9]/
/mno/.*[0-9]/
```

`Replace String`

```
/abc/
/def/
/ghi/
/jkl/
/mno/
```

Can I use an `Advanced` filter instead?

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can, just replace all numeric subfolders with nothing. Use the following regular expression to get them:

```
/[0-9]*/
```

With just one filter you will get the same result (and scalable)

**** EDIT

Not sure how accurate will Google Analytics be with repeating elements in a regular expression. I've noticed in your example that not all subfolders follow the same pattern (end /)

[image]

I think, the best approach to this situation could be [using virtual pages](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/pages?hl=en). You can strip/clean the URLs with your programming language and create [clean paths to be sent to Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference?hl=en#page).

> The easiest way would be with Google Tag Manager: [javascript regular expression](https://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html) + [virtual pages](https://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2014/09/10/fire-virtual-pageview-google-tag-manager/)

Comment: Replace `/[0-9]*/` with `/`

Comment: I think that using a `Search and replace` filter where `Search = /[0-9]*/` and Replace is `/` does not seem to work. I think the filter picks up the first numeric subfolder. 

So it will pick up `/abc/1064431/` making to `/abc/`
but it will not pick `/abc/1064431/def/1064432` making it to `/abc/def/1064432`

Comment: I just updated my answer according to your new examples

Comment: I tested the `Search and Replace` filter. It does not do a global search. It picks up `/abc/123/def` making it to `/abc/def` but it cannot pick up `/abc/123/def/456/` and renders it to `/abc/def/456/`. Unfortunate.